# Javacard leak of memory.

Tags: applet, javacard

I am a beginner in javacard programming and I have implemented an applet using Javacard.
The applet runs for 3 times without deselecting the applet and then I received "0x6f00" in the response data that was returned from the applet?
Is this a leak of memory?

Comment: You are aware that on JavaCards there is no automatic garbage collection? You have to call the garbage collector by hand if it exists. Anyway it is a common style not to create new instances of objects at run-time, only at installation time.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a leak of memory of course. But without additional knowledge it is hard to be sure. It does seem to have something to do with state in the applet, otherwise you won't have such behavior. But that does not necessarily mean a memory leak. "Running" only three times does not seem to be much.

Any uncaught exception that is present at the end of the `process` method will generate a `6F00`. The only exception to this rule is `ISOException` which will translate into a status word represented by the reason in the `ISOException` instance. And as any exception in JavaCard is actually a `RuntimeException` it is very easy to not handle the exceptions correctly.

But it is easy to be sure. Create a `try`/`catch` in the `process` method, catch the `SystemException` and check if the reason code is `SystemException.NO_RESOURCE` or `SystemException.NO_TRANSIENT_SPACE`. Then use `ISOException.throwIt(MY_OUT_OF_MEMORY_STATUS_WORD)`. That's the Java Card equivalent of using `System.out` more or less, you can of course also use a debugger if it is available for your Java Card runtime...

Answer (score 1):

The applet runs for 3 times without deselecting the applet and then I received "0x6f00" in the response data that was returned from the applet?

- it should be a response data returned from javacard OS/JCVM

Is this a leak of memory?

- Possibly. My advice would be don't initialize any variable in the repeated process, say, process(APDU apdu) method. for example:

  ```
  Public class ExampleClass extends Applet {
      Public byte[] b1;
      public byte[] b2;
      ...
      public void process (APDU apdu){
          b2 = new byte[5];               X
      }    
  }
  ```

  Above is not encouraged because every time your applet processes an incoming APDU using process(), the javacard OS must create a byte array in the card flash which will be exhausted very fast this way. Best practice is to initialize variables in the applet instantiation, say, in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is the behavior repeatable? If yes, try checking your code, ensure there is no `new` keyword except in constructor. Reuse variables by creating and using common buffer called "workBuffer", and/or use global RAM buffers such as APDU buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize this Byte array into constructor only (as constructor call only once)
"b2 = new byte[5];"
Else it will occupied EEPROM each Process(..) Call with separate array.

Best of Luck !